# Decision tree (rpart) will not split even with cp=0

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I have an example of dataset where decision tree (rpart) would not split, even with cp = 0. Here is link to the date [unsplittable](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14xC2UfhkMZQceDPnZir4BuvHcWQICIf1/view?usp=share_link). I think even if you take purely random dataset, it will split, it is pretty hard to find something that does not split completely. I am trying to compute  splits manually and see any improvements in Gini index. Here is my code anyway:

```
library(rpart)
df<- read_csv(file = 'df.csv')
df$x <- as.factor(df$x)

fit <- rpart(x ~ ., method = 'class',
             data = df,
             control = rpart.control(cp=0))
summary(fit)
printcp(fit)
```

And here is output:

```
Classification tree:
rpart(formula = x ~ ., data = df, method = "class", control = rpart.control(cp = 0))

Variables actually used in tree construction:
character(0)

Root node error: 16/186 = 0.086022

n= 186 

  CP nsplit rel error xerror xstd
1  0      0         1      0    0
```